# Masking an UIImage and set colored image instead

Tags: ios, uiimage, uigesturerecognizer, uicolor

I'm working on an App which works with gestureRecognizer. 
 With gestures it is possible to select an UIImage (such as rectangle.png) and it is possible with a UIPopoverView to change the color of that image by selecting a color for the selected image.

This image lay in a UIImageView and I think the best solution is to mask that image and set a colored image with the dame size and frame instead.

Is it the right way? How can I optimize my approach? 
Which could be the best practice for this requirement?

Answer (score 1):

```
 (UIImage *)maskImage:(UIColor *)maskColor
{
    CGRect rect = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.size.width, self.size.height);

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(rect.size);

    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextTranslateCTM(context, 0, rect.size.height);
    CGContextScaleCTM(context, 1.0, -1.0);
    CGContextClipToMask(context, rect, self.CGImage);
    CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, maskColor.CGColor);
    CGContextFillRect(context, rect);

    UIImage *smallImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return smallImage;
}
```